# Flash movie not showing up in IE8 on my PC. Can someone take a look?

Tags: flash, internet-explorer-8

I have a flash movie on a login page that shows up fine in every browser apart from IE8 (surprise surprise!), where I just see a red cross in a square. You can see what I mean if you look at the page in IE:

http://monthlymixup.com/index.php

Here is the relevant code:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="mixup.swf" width="800" height="445">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
</object>
```

The movie was created in Flash 10 with ActionScript 3. Does anyone have any suggestions as to why it is isn't working in IE?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did some more googling around and found out that I needed to enter the code as follows:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="mixup.swf" width="800" height="445"> <param name="wmode" value="transparent"> <param name="movie" value="mixup.swf">
```

For the flicker at the start of the flash movie, where the frame could be seen before the movie started, I needed to preload the flash movie.

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/415/tn_4150.html

> To ensure that the most browsers will play your Flash Player movies, you should place the EMBED tag nested within the OBJECT tag as shown in the above example. ActiveX-enabled browsers will "ignore" the EMBED tag inside the OBJECT tag. Netscape and **Microsoft** browsers using the Flash Plugin will not recognize the OBJECT tag and will read only the EMBED tag.

Here's a quick example:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="mixup.swf" width="800" height="445">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <embed href="mixup.swf" quality=high width="800" height="445" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></embed>
</object>
```

Put that on your page and see how it works. You may need to tweak styles a little.

Comment: Thanks.  In fact, I did some more googling around and found out that I needed to enter the code as follows: `<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="mixup.swf" width="800" height="445">
 <param name="wmode" value="transparent"> <param name="movie" value="mixup.swf">` this now shows up in IE, whereas when I tried your example, nothing showed up still.  I am still seeing a flash of the frame of the movie and the login boxes before the movie loads.  Do you know why this is happening?
</object>`  If you use IE you can see what I mean here: [link] (http://monthlymixup.com/)

Comment: I will have to switch to my Windows machine to test this further. I'll get back to you.